# Building CUnit with cygwin on windows

Tags: testing, cygwin, cunit

Can anyone explain me, how to build CUnit on Windows using cygwin?

Only found an example using mingw

[Building CUnit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514408/building-cunit-on-windows)

Call of make Fails (no such command).

Anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is not clear, and you should include more on what you have tried already.

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test.html

Comment: I want to build the library for CUnit with cygwin. I followed the instruction above, got a fail when calling "make".
Cygwin is already installed.

Comment: "Call of make Fails (no such command)" -- do you have `make` installed? Or is it another command that isn't found? Either way, re-run cygwin setup.exe and be sure everything you need is installed.

Comment: Ok. This was the first step.

Now I have a Problem with the build itself, there are some misconfigured paths.

Comment: "The Compiler cannot create the executeables"

Answer (score 0):

There was a Problem with the make and the "config"-file was missing.

After this I can create the libs.