# How to install CUnit on Windows

Tags: c, windows, bash, cunit

I've downloaded the library to my desktop but when I try and install it by running the `./configure` command I get an error:

`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

I've looked at 2 existing questions on SO ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514408/building-cunit-on-windows) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891151/building-cunit-with-cygwin-on-windows)) but they didn't solve my problem. Have I downloaded it correctly? I downloaded and extracted the folder to my desktop then opened the **Bash terminal** in the library's home directory and executed the `./configure` command.

Would be very grateful if someone could help, I'm out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

CUnit-2.1-3.tar.bz2 ? configure is missing from the archive :)
there is a file called "bootstrap"
try 
chmod +x bootstrap
./bootstrap

Comment: Ah really? that's strange. I just opened the Bash terminal in the library's home directory and executed that command you said. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: i don't know, i downloaded the archive out of curiosity, usually you have to launch the command "make" and "make install"

Comment: when I run the command you said it completes successfully but when I go onto to run the `make` command I get `bash: make: command not found`. Have you got any suggestions on what I could do to get it working?